# Deleting lists with foreign number of letter

Tags: python, list

I am learning to work with lists and I've had the thought of how do I delete a list that has any foreign number or letter?

Let's suppose I have a list: `[['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 't', 'j', 'a']]`

and I want to delete the list with "t" and "j" (the last list). I want to say "if there are values other than "0", "1", "2" or "3", then delete the list" but I am not sure how to do that. I know that there are operators like "any" and "all" but is there an equivalent to "other"?

so far I've tried

```
 for item in listt:
     if any(('a','b','c','d')) not in item:
        data.remove(item)
```

But this removes lists that ONLY contain foreign items
I need it to remove all foreign characters (128 ascii characters or more) apart form a b c and d

Comment: give it a shot with `any`. post your code and a lot of people would be happy to help.

Comment: a simple approach will be to iterate over all the individual list inside you 2D list and identify the list which contains those letters and then use list.remove to remove those individual list from the main list. worth a try

Comment: your parentheses in `any` are the first problem. The second being the logic. Look at the answers below for the correct use of `any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "if there are values other than "0", "1", "2" or "3", then delete the list"

You can use [set.difference()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) to see if there are any other values then [0, 1, 2, 3].

And you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to iterate through all your lists:

```
foo = [['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ... , ['a', 'a', 't', 'j', 'a']]
reference_list = set('abcd')

[l for l in foo if not (set(l) - reference_list)]
```

Results in:

```
[['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'],
 ['c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
 ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'],
 ['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'],
 ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'],
 ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']]
```

set.difference() would give you the different values between two unique sets, which can be used to see if there are any additional values in your case.

List comprehensions are preferred over for loops, but they essentially do the same thing, if a for loop is more understandable you can break the expression above to a for loop, it looks like this:

```
new_foo = []
for l in foo:
    if not (set(l) - reference_list):
        new_foo.append(l)
```

---

**Edit:**

After your edit looking at your: `if any(('a','b','c','d')) not in item`. Which I assume you are trying to remove all lists that does not have **all** `[a, b, c, d]`.

You can simply do that by changing the priority on set.difference:

```
(reference_list - set(l))
```

While this would not accept `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']` as a valid list, the other would.

---

Predefined a reference list to compare with. Thanks to @Eric Duminil's comment.

Comment: It looks good. One minor nitpick: you could define a variable containing `set('abcd')` before using the list comprehension. You recreate it at each step otherwise

Comment: @Eric Yeah, you're right. I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is to remove the sublist which contains `'t','j'` from the list.

```
l=[['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 't', 'j', 'a']]

# list of unwanted chars
l2=['t','j']
for x in l:
    for y in x:
        if y in l2:
            print(y)
            l.remove(x)
            break
print(l)
```

Output

```
[['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']]
```

Since, OP wants only sublists with `a,b,c,d`

```
# list of required chars
l3=['a','b','c','d']

for x in l:
    for y in x:
        if not y in l3:
            l.remove(x)
            break
print(l)
```

Output

```
[['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']]
```

Comment: can this be improved to delete all foreign objects, for example 'w', '2', '?' etc but instead of writing them all out, i could just say "if other than original letters present, then delete"

Comment: I was considering listing all 128 ascii characters but it would take a lot of time

Comment: @kate it's better to list the required chars and check rather than listing all unwanted chars. updated to accommodate that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'], ['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 't', 'j', 'a']]
for b in a:
  if 't' in b:
      a.remove(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing from the original (which is also fine but covered by the other answers) you can create a new `list` or even re-create the original one with a `list-comprehension` like so:

```
original = [['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 't', 'j', 'a']]
unwanted_chars = ['t', 'j']

new = [sublist for sublist in original if not any(x in sublist for x in unwanted_chars)]
print(new)  # -> [['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a']]
```

---

Another option would be to use `filter` with a `lambda`-expression:

```
new = list(filter(lambda x: any(y not in x for y in unwanted_chars), original))
print(new)  # -> [['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a']]
```

To avoid creating a new `list` (`new`) just replace `new` with `original` and your initial `list` will be updated.

Also note that if your sublists in `original` are long, you should consider using `set`s that have much faster membership testing capabilities.